# Response False when i am publishing on IIS

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, web, post, request

i have the following problem:

I published a Web Service and i am not able to communicate with the SQL Server.
If i am sending the same POST-Request to the local project i am getting 'true' and it is writing back to the database.

This one works: localhost:1052/save
This one is not: localhost/wsc/save

Do you have any idea to solve this?

Comment: Obviously, the second URL is missing the port number

Comment: I am running the web service on the port :80 under IIS but i can access the webservice via http://localhost/wsc/save on the browser.

Comment: I don't get that - the first URL you've shared uses the port `1052` to access the webservice. That's not the same as port `80`